# Unity C# Yield WaitForSeconds within For Loop Only Works Once

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I am trying to use two yields within a coroutine loop (because I need to iterate out arrays with pauses between each loop).

The first loop works correctly, with all the yields working for the right amount of time. By the second loop, the yield return new WaitForSeconds() begins counting down right away, not waiting for the yield and code before it to complete (it seems). By the time of the third loop, the timing is all off.

I tried using a while loop instead of a for but got the same result.

TLDR: I need to loop out my arrays with pauses between each one. How can I use more than one yield past the first loop through in a coroutine?

```
public IEnumerator doPathfinding()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < waypoint.Length; i++)
    {

        // get first waypoint from array
        var _waypoint = waypoint[i];

        // get node on A* of cloest waypoint
        closestPointOnNavmesh = AstarPath.active.GetNearest(_waypoint.transform.position, NNConstraint.Default).clampedPosition;

        // Move towards destination
        ai.destination = closestPointOnNavmesh;

        // Wait until within X range of waypoint
        yield return new WaitUntil(() => distanceReached == true);

        // Agent is now at waypoint and automatically stops. Wait 5 seconds before looping to next waypoint.
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(5f);

    }

    Debug.Log("Loop End");
}


    public override void OnUpdate()
    {

        // Get current distance to the target. If distance is less than offset, then sent event.    
        currentDistance = Vector3.Distance(go.transform.position, closestPointOnNavmesh);
        if(currentDistance <= arrivalOffset.Value)
        {
            distanceReached = true;
        }
        else
        {
            distanceReached = false;
        }


    }
```

Comment: @ThomasWeller : In Unity `WaitForSeconds` is a class used to make a [coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) wait for a specified amount of time. You can see this as a `Thread.sleep` (even if it's not the same thing)

Comment: @Hellium: ok, thanks.

Comment: Is anything setting `distanceReached` to `false` between iterations? You haven't really told us anything about `distanceReached`...

Comment: The distanceReached is running on update, so that it keeps checking the game object AI, to get its location.

Ill update original post with code, at the bottom.

Comment: @Hellium I think a `Task.Delay` is a better comparison than `Thread.Sleep`

Comment: So I found the answer. It was the variable distanceReached , which was being set to true as my gameobject agent both enterted a valid distance, and then again when it exited. When it exited it set the variable to true again, and restarted the entire loop once again.

What I did to solve it, was may an array of distanceReached bools, and iterate through them with each loop. // I tried to post this an answer, but it will only let me post once per day??

Comment: Btw remember that `OnUpdate` is not being called every frame. The method that is called every frame is `Update` (among others,, https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html )

Answer (score 1):

The code inside the couroutine is fine, it works as intended.

Most probably, based on the issue you reported, you're calling more than once the coroutine at the same time.

Use a `bool` to check if the coroutine has already started or not, like this:

```
bool isDoPathFindingRunning = false;
IEnumerator = doPathFinding();

private void Awake() {
    pathFinding = doPathfinding();
}

private void WhereeverYouStartCoroutine() {
    if (!isDoPathFindingRunning)
        StartCoroutine(pathFinding);
}

public IEnumerator doPathfinding() {
    isDoPathFindingRunning = true;
    // Do your stuff
    isDoPathFindingRunning = false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try. I am actually just calling it once in start(). StartCoroutine(doPathfinding());

Comment: It may be called from two different game objects, a mistake that happens especially if you have a lot of GOs in the scene. Do a simple check: comment out everything from the coroutine, and log something like `Debug.Log("doPathFinding started")` - check if it happens just once or more than once.